# apt-cache does not show older versions of a package

Tags: apt, apt-cache

I need to downgrade jenkins from 2.54 to 2.53. Repo is set up as follows:

```
$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/jenkins.list
deb http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org/debian binary/
```

The repo contains version 2.53 so I try to install it like so:

```
$ sudo apt-get install jenkins=2.53
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Version '2.53' for 'jenkins' was not found
```

OK, let's check policy:

```
$ apt-cache policy jenkins
jenkins:
  Installed: 2.54
  Candidate: 2.54
  Version table:
 *** 2.54 0
        500 http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org/debian/ binary/ Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

No. How about madison?

```
$ apt-cache madison jenkins
   jenkins |       2.54 | http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org/debian/ binary/ Packages
```

That's a no too.

How do I get that version into the cache so that I can install it? I'm a Red Hat guy, new to apt :(

EDIT:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
Ign http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease
...
Hit http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org binary/ Packages
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security InRelease
Ign http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org binary/ Translation-en_US
Ign http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org binary/ Translation-en
...
```

this shows only the latest version of the package:

```
$ aptitude versions jenkins
```

Still no:

```
$ sudo apt-get install jenkins=2.53
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Version '2.53' for 'jenkins' was not found
```

Comment: That Package version has presumably been removed from the repo

Comment: It is there, you can check yourself: http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org/debian/

Comment: but, oddly, their Packages file only mentions one version: http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org/debian/binary/Packages.gz I think the software they use for their repository doesn't support multiple versions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a look at this file:

```
less /var/lib/apt/lists/pkg.jenkins.io_debian_binary_Packages
```

You will see the only version provided for your chosen distro is 2.54, actually `apt-cache` data comes from here too.

And as you already seen, other versions are available in form of `.deb` format as their descriptions stats:

> If you need `*.deb` for a specific version, use these.

grab you specific versions `deb` file, use `gdebi` or `dpkg -i` to install it.